# momentjs returns wrong day name

Tags: javascript, momentjs

This returns Wednesday, but it's Thursday

```
console.log(moment("7-03-2019").format("dddd")); //Wednesday
```

7-03-2019 is Thursday but `moment("7-03-2019").format("dddd")`

```
console.log(moment().format("dddd")); //Thursday
```

What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/da0t4pnx/

Comment: July 3, 2019 is a Wednesday,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment.js is parsing the given input in "MM-DD-YYYY" format.

It would benefit if you mentioned the format with the input. Refer: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Example:

```
console.log(moment("7-03-2019", "DD-MM-YYYY").format("dddd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

July 3, 2019 (07-03-2019) is a Wednesday (because the dates are in the format MM-DD-YYYY)
If you want March 7, 2019 (03-07-2019) you should do

```
console.log(moment("03-07-2019").format("dddd")); //Thursday
```